# What model/year is this frame?

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I recently got this frame second hand after mine was damaged in an attempted theft. Having a couple of issues refitting, I wonder if anyone can identify the model/year?

[image: Tifosi bike frame, black and silver]

Comment: The brand belongs to Chicken Cycle Kit. It's fairly old and could be from 1999 to 2010, maybe. I don't imagine you'll have any trouble finding parts to fit: it's all pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Thanks, don't know if you'd have an idea of derailleur hangers that would attach?

Comment: http://gearmechhanger.com/WebRoot/Namesco2/Shops/950018694/5D13/8210/41CB/8FD0/E68A/C0A8/1911/1001/D38_preview.jpeg Does it measure up?

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. Bike is in the workshop at the moment, I'll check that one tomorrow.